# Can't append FormData() object with multiple compressed images on the client side

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, image-processing

I am trying to compress images on the client side using [Compressor JS](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/compressorjs/) before making the request because it takes a lot of time to upload them in original size.

**The problem i ran into:**

I have a FormData() object declared as 'fd' in my code and when i try appending an image to it via the success hook function in Compressor JS just doesn't do anything (the object remains as it was). **Here is the code**

```
var fd = new FormData();
const fileList = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;

for (file of fileList) {
                
    new Compressor(file, {
        quality: 0.4,
        maxWidth: 800,
        success: function (result) {
            fd.append('compressedImage', result, result.name);
        },
    });
}
```

Basically I am looping through the array of files and compressing each image one by one.


**What I have noticed:**
By making a new empty array before the loop and append each image to it should give me all the compressed images in an array. **This is what i mean**

```
const fileList = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;

compressedImgs = [];

for (file of fileList) {

    new Compressor(file, {
        quality: 0.4,
        maxWidth: 800,
        success: function (result) {
            compressedImgs.push(result);
        },
    });
}
```

**HOWEVER**, `console.log(compressedImgs)` outputs this (nothing unusual because i added 2 images to the input):
[Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob41c.png)

But when i try to log an element of the array (for example compressedImages[0]), outputs **undefined**.

I need a way to put my compressed files into the FormData() to be able to send them to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the wetransfer link I passed you there is a complete example using the CompressorJS library and saving in PHP. It is working and maybe it will help you with your issue in case you are overlooking something.

Also, if it is helpful and you can fix the problem it would be helpful if you comment on how you solved it.

Below is the code that works normally for me:

`index.html`

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
<script>

    const formData = new FormData()

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        const fileInput = document.querySelector('[type=file]')

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {

            const files = e.target.files
            const promises = []

            for (let file of files) {

                promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    new Compressor(file, {
                        quality: 0.6,
                        success(result) {
                            formData.append('files[]', result, result.name)
                            console.log(result)
                            resolve()
                        },
                        error(err) {
                            console.log(err.message)
                            reject()
                        },
                    })
                }))

            }

            Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                console.log(Array.from(formData.values()))
                const request = new XMLHttpRequest()
                request.open("POST", "./files-handler.php")
                request.send(formData)
            })

        })

    })

</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.0.7/compressor.min.js"></script>
```

`files-handler.php`

```php
$data = [];

$data['_FILES'] = $_FILES;
$data['_POST'] = $_POST;
$data['uploadedFiles'] = [];

$uploadDir = __DIR__ . '/uploads/';

$data['uploadDir'] = $uploadDir;

if (!file_exists($uploadDir)) {
    mkdir($uploadDir, 0777);
}

$filesInput = $_FILES['files'];
$filesName = $filesInput['name'];
$filesTmpName = $filesInput['tmp_name'];
$filesError = $filesInput['error'];

foreach ($filesName as $index => $name) {

    if ($filesError[$index] == \UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $toPath = $uploadDir . uniqid() . '_' . $name;
        $uploaded = move_uploaded_file($filesTmpName[$index], $toPath);
        if ($uploaded) {
            $data['uploadedFiles'][] = $toPath;
        }
    }

}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This is it! It solved the problem. The actual problem was probably because I didn't have the promises and the form data object was being sent to the server without the compressor to finish its work as it is an async process

Comment: After the first answer wasn't enough I figured, I'm glad it solved your problem.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `compressedImage` to `compressedImage[]`.

Something like:

```js
let formData = new FormData()
let fileInput = document.querySelector('[type=file]')

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    
    let files = e.target.files
    
    for(let file of files){
        formData.append('files[]', file)
    }
    
    console.log(Array.from(formData.values()))
    
})
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple/>
```

EDIT 1:
It would be useful to see the form submission code and also some of the server code.

However, one other thing occurs to me are you submitting the files with `Content-Type` `multipart/form-data`?

The above is important for submitting files to the server.

Comment: I applied the changes you suggested but still the formData doesn't append, I consider this is because after compression the file is converted to a blob, but i tried making it a file again and still no result. By the way, on the server-side it shows a warning that there is no such index.

Comment: There is a working example of sending and saving in PHP: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/061dfede66f1522076bf533fa77e41c020210429204057/8c7240

Comment: Yes, content-type is multipart/formdata, but the idea is that i cant even put the files in a simple array, they also don't show up there if i try to log them by index, however logging the entire array does show them correctly, just take a careful look at the example i presented in the question, this is somerhing very weird